# Basic question Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I need to find all the values of $a$ and $n$ that gives $\{0,a\}$ is a subgroup of the group $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$.
Assum $n \geq 2$ and $a \neq 0$.

Actually I thing that for each $a$ and $n$ we will get that this is a subgroup ($0$ identity element)
Am I wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{0,1\}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for $n \geq 3$.

Hint: Notice that $\{0,a\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ iff $2a=0$.

Comment: I don't understand why 2a=0

Comment: $\{0,a\}$ needs to be stable under addition, that is $a+a \in  \{0,a\}$.

Comment: @Natte: In fact, you need the set to be closed under addition  so $a+a\in\{0,a\}$.

Comment: So why for n>=3 it's not ok? N=3 z={0,1,2} and 1+1 is fine

Comment: @Natte: $\{0,1\}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ because $2=1+1 \notin \{0,1\}$: $\{0,1\}$ is not stable under addition.

Comment: Ok thanks I was little confused so there is no a that will make this set a subgroup

Comment: @Natte: In fact, there is always $a=0$. Otherwise, you have to investigate when $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has an element of order $2$.

Comment: I was given that a is not zero so...Thank you very much for your help